# Viewcontroller question in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

I'm a iPhone App newbie. I have a viewcontroller and want to load a different viewcontroller directly after the first one is initialized.

Any help would be appreaciated. :)

Cheers
Sebastian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a UINavigationController. -initWithRootViewController using your first view controller, and then -pushViewController:animated: with your second view controller, passing NO for animated.